# Get instagram user (owner) id from image url

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

does anyone know if it's possible to reverse engineer the poster user id for a given instagram image url, for example, given a url such as:

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.5881-15/s320x320/e15/123457_0107357035024633_1369594222_n.jpg
```

would it be possible to fetch the `user_id` and `image_id` from the above url?

Comment: Bumping this in 2022